# How to calculate a determinant of a 2x2 symmetry block matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'd like to calculate the determinant of the matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -A & B^\star  \\
        -B & A^\star  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$A$, $B$ are $L\times L$ complex matrix.

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are real matrix, the determinant can be easily calculated:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -A & B  \\
        -B & A  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        A & B  \\
        B & A  \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
.
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
        A & B  \\
        B & A  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=\det(A-B)\det(A+B)
$$

Is there a similar formula when $A$ and $B$ are complex matrix? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am blown away by this fact about real matrices on the last line -- I didn't know that was true. However does one prove it? It's nothing to do with real matrices -- it seems to be true for matrices over an arbitrary commutative ring.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thank you for your comments. I learned the last line from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), I do not know how to prove that. Of course, A and B can be complex in the last line. I want to know whether there is a similar formula for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

If $\mathbf {A^*}$ is invertible you can use the general result:
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf A&\mathbf B\\
\mathbf C&\mathbf D
\end{bmatrix}= \det (\mathbf D) \det(\mathbf A-\mathbf B\mathbf D^{-1}\mathbf C)
$$
that is a consequence of the identity:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf A&\mathbf B\\
\mathbf C&\mathbf D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf I&\mathbf 0\\
\mathbf{-D^{-1}}\mathbf C&\mathbf D
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf A -\mathbf B\mathbf {D^{-1}}\mathbf C&\mathbf B\\
\mathbf 0&\mathbf D
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf I&\mathbf B\\
\mathbf 0&\mathbf D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf A -\mathbf B\mathbf {D^{-1}}\mathbf C&\mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0&\mathbf D
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you Emilio. This formula is not my goal, I'm looking for a formula similar to det(A+B) det(A-B).